# Bottom navigation view crashes app after I add a new item

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation bar in my app, and it was working fine until I added a new item

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_month"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_month"
        android:title="Month"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_week"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_week"
        android:title="Week"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_day"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today"
        android:title="Day"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:title="logout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_switch_calendars"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
        android:title="Calendars"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Up until I added that last item, it worked. What's going on here and how can I fix it?  I'm getting an warning in the view that contains it saying "failed to instantiate one or more classes", but again if I remove that last item, the warning goes away. I also have 2 render problems, but those are also there without the last item as well.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you add crash log.

Answer (score 1):

BottomNavigationView supports max 5 items. It might be failing because you're trying to add the 6th. You can check this number via BottomNavigationView's [getMaxItemCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView?hl=en#getmaxitemcount) method.